# New edge does not split face

Tags: edges

I subdivided a face. I then connected the newly added vertex to an existing vertex by selecting both vertices and pressing <kbd>F</kbd>

The now newly created edge crosses an existing face, but the face is not partitioned by the new edge (as can be seen in the screenshot below). So, I obviously did something wrong.

[image]

So, my question is: how do I split the existing face in two right where the edge is?

P.S.
I'm *reaaly* new to blender so I don't know the correct terminology to search for; I hope this question is not answered here already.

Comment: Delete this old face. Select all the unconnected edges and press F to make a new face. This will fix the current situation. Otherwise, before creating the edge use the knife tool to cut the face. The knife tool can snap to the vertices which you want to connect.

Comment: Thanks for the super quick comment, it worked. Maybe expand your comment into an answer so I can accept it.

Comment: Try J instead of F. I've been using this since forever, so I don't remember if it's available by default or if it's part of an addon.

Comment: @Duane Dibbley, your solution works a lot faster than deleting a face, with all the possible complications it implies. Post it as an answer. :o)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

By selecting the vertices and pressing <kbd>F</kbd> you are simply creating a new edge. The faces connected to the vertices are not changed, this behaviour correct.

In this position, delete the problematic face.
Select all the vertices and/or edges, which need to be fill and press 
<kbd>F</kbd> to fill them with new faces.

Alternatively, before creating the edge which intersects the face, press <kbd>K</kbd> to cut the face with the [Knife Tool](https://docs.blender.org/manual/en/latest/modeling/meshes/editing/subdividing/knife.html#knife-tool). The knife tool can snap to the vertices along the faces' edge.

Answer (score 7):

<kbd>F</kbd> will create non-manifold (bad) geometry. In practice, if <kbd>J</kbd> cuts the edge you want, use it. Use <kbd>F</kbd> to fill in new geometry. Use <kbd>J</kbd> to modify existing geometry.

Comment: Providing keyboard shortcuts without saying what the shortcut does is not very helpful for new users. What does "J" do?  If you don't explain your answer, they'll just be back the next time they have the same problem but don't know that the same solution applies.

Answer (score 0):

<kbd>J</kbd> instead of  <kbd>F</kbd> works perfectly for this.

Select the vertex you want to divide with and press  <kbd>J</kbd>.

Comment: Hi, thanks for the post. This site is not a regular forum, answers should be substantial and thoroughly explain the solution and required workflow. One liners and short tips rarely make for a good answer. If you can [edit] your post and provide some more details about the procedure and why it works feel free to restore it, otherwise it may be deleted or converted into a comment. Perhaps add a few [images](https://blender.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/963) illustrating the workflow and final results. See [How do I write a good answer?](https://blender.stackexchange.com/help/how-to-answer)